# Unreachable statement for PHPUnit achieving 100% Code Coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I let PHPUnit generate a code coverage and XDebug tell it that some lines have not been reached:

```
public static function execute()
{
    static $hasRun = false;

    if (false == $hasRun)
    { // first run: init Pat
        self::registerAutoloader();
        self::registerPatIncludeDir();

        $hasRun = true;
    }

    return $hasRun;
}
```

This runs before it can be tested. So the inner block won't run again.
Is there any way to reach the block in the if ?
Or a way to make one single test in PHPUnit run first?

Comment: You can try with process isolation. I think it runs each test separated. Also, instead of the static inside the function, you could make it of the class so at least you could modify this value (e.g. via reflection). In every case it does not belong in there, you have written code in a way you basically ask for not having this tested :)

Comment: $hasRun will never be used by any other method but shall be accessible by any other instance. That is why I made it static inside the function. If I need this in the class as a new field then when to use static variables in functions?

Comment: Static variables in static class methods in PHP in my eyes never make a sense. Static variables in global functions can make sense for the cases outlined in the PHP manual. Personally IMHO one should avoid static variables totally, using them is often a sign of missing thoughts. If while testing I run into a problem with a static because I yet have not dealt with it, I refactor the code so that the static variable goes away.

Comment: Check this out. Feel free if you need follow up

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178189/phpunit-code-coverage-0-files-analysed-when-including-file-with-function-in-it/16306961#16306961